# RegEx find "../" or "./"

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get regex to tell me if a path contains `./` or `../`.  This is to check a user doesn't look beyond their area. If the input contains a period before a forward slash it wont be accepted.

E.g.

```
/user/selected/path/ - Ok 
./user/selected/path/ - Failed 
../user/selected/path/ - Failed
```

The forward slash will be replaced with DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR so works for unix and windows paths.

Comment: Why don’t you [remove the dot segments properly](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5.2.4)?

Comment: What do you want to do if `./` or `../` is found? Remove those segments from the path? Return `false`, or something else?

Comment: @Gumbo Because usually you come across ......../......./.......././../

Comment: @DavidThomas Im happy with a bool, not going to try and edit the string.

Comment: @arbme I said [remove them properly](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5.2.4). The mentioned algorithm is aware of such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
if (preg_match('#\.(\.)?/#', $path, $match)) echo "Error";
```

If you need to check for ../ or ./ only in the beginning you must use this

```
if (preg_match('#^\.(\.)?/#', $path, $match)) echo "Error";
```

Comment: Note that the first regex will match `/foo./bar`, and neither will match a bare `..` or `.`.  As an aside, the capture group is unnecessary:  `'#\.\.?/#'`.

Answer (score 6):

Checking for the existence of ".." is an imperfect solution to the problem.

If you want to prevent the user from breaking out of a base directory, check whether the `realpath()` result of the path (which will take into account relative paths) is still underneath the root path.

Example:

```
$root = "/my/user/basepath";
$requested_path = $_GET["input"]; // or whatever

$real_path = realpath($root."/".$requested_path);

if (strpos($real_path, $root) !== 0)
 die ("Illegal path");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd

a) recommend strpos for something this simple, not regex functions.

```
$usrPath = '../some/path/';
if (strpos($usrPath, '.' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) !== false){
    die('oh no you don\'t');
}
```

b) Recommend making sure your server setup and filesystem permissions are set to prevent any chance of a user getting 'beyond their area', rather then programmatic methods.

Comment: Note that this use of strpos will match `foo./bar` and will not match a path that is literally `..` or `.`.

Comment: I think the !== (not !=) means it should match '.' and '..', unless I'm being dense. To check that the dot starts the string do it as `if (strpos($usrPath, '.') === 0) {die('oh no you don\'t');}`

Comment: But to be honest, @pekka says what I was trying to say more eloquently. No strpos/preg_match solution is clever.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myString = "some/path";
if (preg_match('/(\.\.\/|\.\/)/', $myString)) { 
    echo "found ../ or ./ in path"; 
}
```

Comment: Is that `//i` modifier necessary?  Do you have uppercase and lowercase dots or slashes in your locale? :)

Comment: Lol, no I guess that's not going to do much, huh?